# How to keep variable value after clicking a link

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I searched for a whole day but couldn't find solution to this. I'd like to build very simple 'prev' 'next' pagination, for that I'd like to keep value in a $counter variable so that after clicking a link 'next', system would via GET load next 10 rows from MySQL database and variable would be incremented, something like

$counter += 10;

I first needed to declare $counter variable and set it to 0, but after I click 'next' link, page refreshes and counter variable is reset back to 0, actually not moving with database listing. But I cannot go on without assigning initial value to this variable. It looks like a catch 22 to me.

I tried to solve this with SESSION but had same problem. I have spent 12 hrs trying to decypher this, analysed many pagination samples on net so pls help me if you can. Thanks. If that is silly q, sorry.

Comment: Sessions, get or cookies, sessions or cookies are probably the easiest but for pagination get will also be sufficient but then you need to update the url all the time.

Comment: I recommend sessions because of security. Granted, i know that there are a lot of flaws when it comes to sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic technique that I have used to preserve the value of a variable such as `$counter` is to pass it as variable and reload the form.

When the form is initially opened, `$counter` would have no value.

The initial code when the form is first opened is:

```
    if (!isset($_REQUEST['page']))
        {$counter = 1;
                } else {
        $counter = $_REQUEST['page'];}
```

You can then set `$counter` to whatever value you like.  You then pass the value that you set for `$counter` by reloading your form.  The example below, to reload your form, would have to be modified for your situation.

```
    echo "<tr><td> <a href='index.php?content=edit_company_form&page=$counter'>$company</td></tr>"
```

Moving to the `next` and `previous` pages is handled in the same manner,  add another variable to be passed to the reloaded form.

Comment: Hey @Steve thanks, it worked! Key was in inserting variable $counter into form. I inserted something more static like ?page=true or ?page=1 to serve only as a control whether user clicked on a link, but inserting $counter actually increments and keeps its new value on the next pass. Now I will sleep better, thank you :)